# "Editar resumo" (Edit summary) deveria ser traduzido como "Resumo da edição"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Quando se edita uma pergunta/resposta, o label "Edit summary" está traduzido como "Editar resumo" (lit. "edit the summary", verbo na voz imperativa). Uma tradução mais correta seria "Resumo da edição" (lit. "summary of the edit", substantivo).

Comment: @Gabe no meu continua "Editar resumo"

Comment: @JorgeB. As edições de tradução vão pro ar no próximo deploy do site. Quando o `rev` lá no final do rodapé mudar, todas as traduções novas são atualizadas!

Comment: @JorgeB. Demora um pouco pras mudanças aparecerem pro usuário (mesmo se ele limpar a cache do navegador). [Essa outra modificação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1965/215), por exemplo, demorou pelo menos um dia pra aparecer pra mim depois que eu a vi.